# appsettings.json is not loaded .net 8 blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, appsettings, .net-8.0, wwwroot

This line causes a null reference exception:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseApiUrl")) });
```

This is my `appsettings.json` that I put in the `wwwroot` folder directly:

```
{
  "BaseApiUrl": "https://localhost:44327"
}
```

Do you know what the problem is?

I expect to have the correct value returned.

Comment: What is the value that you get instead of the expected url?

Comment: `appsettings.json` doesn't belong in `wwwroot`. It belongs in the root of the project, and the build process will copy it to the output folder where it can be loaded into the configuration at startup. If you're moving it around in Visual Studio after you've created it, you might need to manually set it to "Copy if newer". Normally, when you create it in the root of the project, it's already set correctly by the ASP.NET Core SDK project properties.

Comment: This is weird in that you've indicated the line thats failing inside Visual Studio but you're messing around with the age old wwwroot as if you've deployed it. Just open Visual Studio and put the appsettings.json in the root level of your startup project. Then when you deploy make sure the appsettings.json is in the same directory as the DLLs and EXE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AddHttpClient extention

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BaseHttp", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseApiUrl")));
});
```